# Is it possible to update a database with jquery in Symfony2?

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have installed the jsrouting-bundle, and this is my code:

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".pmcontents").hide();
    $(".pmbox").click(function () {
        $(this).css("font-weight", "normal");
        $(this).next().toggle();
        var myValue = $('this').attr('id');
        var DATA = 'sentValue=' + myValue;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: Routing.generate('isread'),
            data: DATA,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("database has been updated");

            }
        });
    });

});
```

**Controller:**

```
public function isreadAction() {
    $request = $this->get('request');
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        var_dump($request->request->get('sentValue'));
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $pm = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Privatemessage')
                ->findBypmid($request->request->get('sentValue'));

        $pm->setIsRead(true);
        $em->flush();
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

**Routing:**

```
isread:
    path:   /game/isread
    defaults: { _controller: LoginLoginBundle:Default:isread }
    requirements:
     _method:  POST
```

But it doesn't work to update the is_read column. Also I get errors on my vendor folder:

[image: Errors]

Comment: If you want to update the database with jQuery you will have to use AJAX to communicate with your server-side database update script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    // Routing.generate = install fosjsroutingbundle
    url: Routing.generate('the_route_of_your_contoller'),
    data: DATA,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
           alert("database has been updated");

        }
    });
```

And the controller will have the persistance/updating role

---

the route, same as normal just add requirements :

```
path:   /..
defaults: { _controller: ..:..:.. }
requirements:
     _method:  POST
```

the response

```
return new Response();
```

with a `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;` at the top of your file

---

2nd edit

i'd do like so :

jquery :

```
var myValue = $('this').attr('id');
//in POST ajax
var DATA = 'sentValue=' + myValue;
```

in controller

```
$request = $this->get('request');
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
{
     $value = $request->request->get('sentValue');
```

Comment: Hi I have done this but it doesn't work yet, I have edited the OP.

Comment: what errors you got ? did you allow post in your route ? i dont see any response (even empty ) in your controller
The vendor thing .. i don't know.

Comment: I did not receive errors, how should the route and the response be like? i'm relative new to symfony so I dont know what you mean

Comment: Ok edited it, but I think there is something wrong with the javascript code, var_dump doesn't work in my controller so the isreadAction isn't called.Is this correct: data: pm_id=$('this').attr('id'),?

Comment: I get this error in console: Error: The route "isread" does not exist.

Comment: looks like your routing bundle is not cofigured properly, can't help you there. check the docs on github

Comment: I resolved it, but now I have following error: "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/SocProNetbeans/web/app_dev.php/game/isread"

Comment: then click on the error you have probably an error in the php script which can be displayed in your favorite browser inspector

Comment: Is this part correct: var myValue = $('this').attr('id');
        var DATA = 'sentValue=' + myValue;, because it gives me this sentValue=undefined

Comment: I have resolved it, $(this) instead of $('this'). Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should try an AJAX call from jquery ($.ajax()), but what you'll need is an request endpoint, that will deliver responses on request, which means that you'll have to build a PHP/Symfony2-Script first and than call it via AJAX:

Concept:

```
User interaction --> jQuery.ajax() --> symfony2_script.php --> jQuery response processing --> view update
```